# php money_format

Tags: php, format, currency

i am trying to remove the .00 at the end of the price

```
 function getMoney($mon) {
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
  return money_format('%.2n', $mon);
 }
```

Thank You,

Comment: Do you want `getMoney(5.20)` to output `$5` or `$5.20`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using this version of the money_format() function:

```
money_format('%.0n', $mon);
```

According to the PHP documentation on money_format (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), making the format string '%.2n' will force the number to be displayed with the decimal point and 2 decimal places to the right of the decimal point, no matter what the cents are, and then format the number according the the locale's national currency format.

By replacing that with '%.0n', you will always remove the decimal at the end of the money. Of course, this will remove the decimal for all values, not just those with .00 at the end. If you want to conditionally remove the .00, check to see if the value of $mon has a fractional part, and if so, display it with '%0.2n'.

Answer (score 4):

It seems on first inspection, your code is *asking* for the cents to be displayed by means of the `'%.2n'`, but I notice the following link on the [PHP function reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#86039) which includes a warning about `set_locale()` on Debian.

You're not using Debian, are you?

Comment: Adding notes for Debian: "If money_format doesn't seem to be working properly, make sure you are defining a valid locale.  For example, on Debian, 'en_US' is not a valid locale - you need 'en_US.UTF-8' or 'en_US.ISO-8559-1'.

This was frustrating me for a while.  Debian has a list of valid locales at /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED; find yours there if it's not working properly." -- http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#86039

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php):

You need to set the right precision as such:

```
function getMoney($mon) {
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
  return money_format('%.0n', $mon);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to remove the cents, but only if there's no cents? There's always the quick and dirty regex:

```
preg_replace("/\\.00^/", "", money_format('%.2n', $mon))
```

Comment: This will not work for European values that use the decimal point as the thousands separator (eg. 2.000.000,00)

Answer (score 0):

nickf is right (kinda), and ben is wrong, your money float variable may have a fractional part but once formatted it could round to 0 cents, so it should always be removed after the fact. nickf's code should be:
`preg_replace('/\.00$/', '', money_format('%.2n', $mon))`